# How to grab a string that is between 2 strings

Tags: vb.net, vb6, split

I was used to VB6 using the split method as the following:

```
Split(Split(strLOL,strCool)(1),strCOOL)(0)
```

With this i was able to grab a string that was between 2 strings for example.

```
"en_us":"hi",
```

`strLOL` was for example: `"en_US":"`  and `strCool` was `",`

So it would grab the string between those two.

How am i possible to do this within VB.NET?

**Edit**:  Let me set this straight. `"en_us":"hi",` is a string i have in a text
file... I have a textbox that contains `"en_us":"hi",` and i want to grab
everything between

- `"en_us":"` and
- `",`

So the desired result is: `hi`

Comment: I don't get it. What is the desired result? A string array where the first string is `en_US":` and the second just `,`? What is the rule, what is the separator? Why is the first `"` removed? Use the code-button in the editor to format code, don't use `""` because that modifies the input strings. We don't know if you want to tell us that this is a  string or if it's part of the string.

Comment: I think it should work in vb.net. What error you're getting?

Comment: @Nadeem_MK: He asks how to do that in VB.NET, so what is the .NET way to do this.

Comment: @TimSchmelter The same code should work identically in vb.net as the Split function is also present in vb.net

Comment: @Nadeem_MK: [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) works different than VB6 [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx). That's why he asks.

Comment: Ok, i am confused...Is the colon (:) the expected result here?

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg: Your edit is risky. Maybe OP just wanted to mark the strings as strings, therefore he used `"`. Now your edfit suggests that they are part of the string. That's why i've asked for clarification above.

Comment: oke let me set this straight.
"en_us":"hi",  is a string i have in a text file.
I did not mean the text between " no , that is the full string.

i have a textbox that containts: "en_us":"hi",
and i want to grab everything between "en_us":" and ",

So the response would be: hi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let me set this straight. "en_us":"hi", is a string i have in a text
>   file... I have a textbox that containts: `"en_us":"hi",` and i want to grab
>   everything between `"en_us":"` and `",` So the response would be: `hi`

You would use [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) in .NET if you want to return a string between two other substrings. You use [`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to find the index of the substrings:

```
Dim str = IO.File.ReadAllText(pathToTextFile) '  "en_us":"hi",
Dim grabBetween1 = """en_us"":"""
Dim grabBetween2 = ""","
Dim indexOf = str.IndexOf(grabBetween1)

Dim result As String
If indexOf >= 0 Then ' default is -1 and indices start with 0
    indexOf += grabBetween1.Length ' now we look behind the first substring that we've already found
    Dim endIndex = str.IndexOf(grabBetween2, indexOf)
    If endIndex >= 0 Then
        result = str.Substring(indexOf, endIndex - indexOf)
    Else
        result = str.Substring(indexOf)
    End If
End If
```

Result is: `hi`

If you insist on using `String.Split` or you want to see what is the equivalent in .NET, here it is:

```
Dim result = str.Split({grabBetween1}, StringSplitOptions.None)(1).Split({grabBetween2}, StringSplitOptions.None)(0)
```

which also returns `hi`. However, that is less readable, much more error-prone, and less efficient.

Comment: Could i use this with a text file with multiple strings of the same, for now example it grabs only the first one, but can i let it loop trough the whole textbox(multiline)?

Comment: So the user provides two strings at each line in the `TextBox`. How are they separated?

Comment: hmm lets say, i have a text file with translations.
here at my intern we have to translate these manualy.
for example i copy the text file into the textbox and want to grab all the strings between: "en_us"," and ",

Comment: @AppieZemmouri: It's still not clear. Of yourse you can use some kind of collection like `String()`(you can use `TextBox.Lines`) and loop that with the same logic as above.  But it's not clear how you want to extract the start-substring and the end-substring. Maybe you should ask another question with proper sample data, a desired result and something that you've tried(show own effort). Then people are happy to help you.

Comment: hey i got something like this now, only i have no idea how to loop it.
http://pastebin.com/GMqzqxCT

Answer (score 0):

You will get the proper result if you use:

```
Dim str = """en_us"":""hi"","   ' This outputs a string with the value `"en_us":"hi",`
Console.WriteLine(str.Split("""")(2)) ' This will get you the string `hi`
```