# how to read all strings that are between 2 other strings

Tags: vb.net, split

i have managed to find a string between 2 specified strings,
the only issue now is that it will only find one and then stop.

how am i possible to make it grab all the strings in a textbox?
the textbox is multiline and i have put a litle config in it.

now i want that the listbox will add all the strings that are between my 2 specified strings.

textbox3.text containts "<"
and textbox 4.text contains ">"

```
Public Function GetClosedText(ByVal source As String, ByVal opener As String, ByVal closer As String) As String
    Dim intStart As Integer = InStr(source, opener)
    If intStart > 0 Then
        Dim intStop As Integer = InStr(intStart + Len(opener), source, closer)
        If intStop > 0 Then
            Try
                Dim value As String = source.Substring(intStart + Len(opener) - 1, intStop - intStart - Len(opener))
                Return value
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return ""
            End Try
        End If
    End If
    Return ""
End Function


usage:
ListBox1.Items.Add(GetClosedText(TextBox1.Text, TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text))
```

Comment: Have you considered perhaps a regular expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way (least lines of code) to do this would be to use a regular expression.  For instance, to find all of that strings enclosed in pointy brackets, you could use this regular expression:

```
\<(?<value>.*?)\>
```

Here's what that all means:

- `\<` - Find a string which starts with a `<` character.  Since `<` has a special meaning in RegEx, it must be escaped (i.e. preceded with a backslash)
- `(?<value>xxx)` - This creates a named group so that we can later access this portion of the matched string by the name `"value"`.  Everything contained in the name group (i.e. where `xxx` is), is considered part of that group.
- `.*?` - This means find any number of any characters, up to, but not including whatever comes next.  The `.` is a wildcard which means any character.  The `*` means any number of times.  The `?` makes it non-greedy so it stops matching as soon as if finds whatever comes next (the closing `>`).
- `\>` - Specifies that matching strings must end with a `>` character.  Since `>` has a special meaning in RegEx, it must also be escaped.

You could use that RegEx expression to find all the matches, like this:

```
Dim items As New List(Of String)()
For Each i As Match In Regex.Matches(source, "\<(?<value>.*?)\>")
    items.Add(i.Groups("value").Value)
Next
```

The trick to making it work in your scenario is that you need to dynamically specify the opening and closing characters.  You can do that by concatenating them to the RegEx, like this:

```
Regex.Matches(source, opener & "(?<value>.*?)" & closer)
```

But the problem is, that will only work if `source` and `closer` are not special RegEx characters.  In your example, they are `<` and `>`, which are special characters, so they need to be escaped.  The safe way to do that is to use the `Regex.Escape` method, which only escapes the string if it needs to be:

```
Private Function GetClosedText(source As String, opener As String, closer As String) As String()
    Dim items As New List(Of String)()
    For Each i As Match In Regex.Matches(source, Regex.Escape(opener) & "(?<value>.*?)" & Regex.Escape(closer))
        items.Add(i.Groups("value").Value)
    Next
    Return items.ToArray()
End Function
```

Notice that in the above example, rather than finding a single item and returning it, I changed the `GetClosedText` function to return an array of strings.  So now, you can call it like this:

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(GetClosedText(TextBox1.Text, TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text))
```

Comment: Thanx man! this works.
Will surely make my internship easier :p

Comment: No problem.  RegEx can be a pain to learn, but it really is a very handy tool.  Even if you don't use it that often in your code, it's still handy even just to use in the `Find` and `Replace` dialog windows in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I ssume you want to loop all openers and closers:

```
' always use meaningful variable/control names instead of
If TextBox3.Lines.Length <> TextBox4.Lines.Length Then 
    MessageBox.Show("Please provide the same count of openers and closers!")
    Return
End If

Dim longText = TextBox1.Text
For i As Int32 = 0 To TextBox3.Lines.Length - 1
    Dim opener = TextBox3.Lines(i)
    Dim closer = TextBox4.Lines(i)
    listBox1.Items.Add(GetClosedText(longText, opener , closer))
Next
```

However, you should use .NET methods as shown [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19046990/284240):

```
Public Function GetClosedText(ByVal source As String, ByVal opener As String, ByVal closer As String) As String
    Dim indexOfOpener = source.IndexOf(opener)
    Dim result As String = ""
    If indexOfOpener >= 0 Then ' default is -1 and indices start with 0
        indexOfOpener += opener.Length ' now look behind the opener
        Dim indexOfCloser = source.IndexOf(closer, indexOfOpener)
        If indexOfCloser >= 0 Then
            result = source.Substring(indexOfOpener, indexOfCloser - indexOfOpener)
        Else
            result = source.Substring(indexOfOpener) ' takes the rest behind the opener
        End If
    End If
    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: @AppieZemmouri: Provide a sample string with one or two openers/closers. It's difficult to help otherwise. Also, use the debugger to see what happens.

Comment: i got this in my textbox with mutiline.
it only grabs the first one and thats hi

    "en_us":"hi","nl_nl":"hoi","sp_sp":"hola"
    "en_us":"bye","nl_nl":"doei","sp_sp":"adios"
    "en_us":"no","nl_nl":"nee","sp_sp":"no"
    "en_us":"sure","nl_nl":"tuurlijk","sp_sp":"seguro"
    "en_us":"fancy","nl_nl":"kleurrijk","sp_sp":"colorido"
    "en_us":"sick","nl_nl":"ziek","sp_sp":"enfermo"

Comment: @AppieZemmouri: And what are the openers/closers? Have you noticed that there are sometimes commas and sometimes not?

Comment: i have noticed that, the openers are: "en_us":" and closers are: ",
i can make all the closers end with ",

Comment: @AppieZemmouri: You want to extract all lines in the textfile and add them to the ListBox? You have described your requirement differently. I thought you have multiple opener/closers in the two textboxes and want to use them on the whole file-text. If you want to use them for every line use `File.ReadAllLines(path)` and use the strings in a loop. Or, if they are already in `TextBox1` use it's `Lines` property and loop that.

Comment: oke i am going to slap myself.

i have a text file that contains translated text,
now i want to grab the text that are between the opener and closer.

opener = "en_us":"
closer = ",

so i want to grab from the following "en_us":"hi",
i want to have hi as a response,
Bu now i import a text file in the textbox1
and as soon i press the extract button it extracts all those words between the closer and opener to the listbox./